# CIS194: Risk!-style "battles"

Tags: beginner, haskell, random, monads, battle-simulation

After reading [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) and using RWH as a reference, I've been doing the exercises from [CIS194](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/), which is often suggested to beginners on `irc://freenode.net/#haskell` and by [this author](http://bitemyapp.com/posts/2014-12-31-functional-education.html). I've just completed Homework 12, which goes with [Lesson 12](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/12-monads.html) and focuses on Monads, **using the template provided [here](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/extras/12-monads/Risk.hs).**

You can find the **complete exercise requirements [here](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/12-monads.pdf).**

It *apparently* works, but I would love some suggestions, stylistically and otherwise, to turn it into proper, idiomatic, clean, readable, *good* Haskell. I'm especially concerned by how monad-specific `>>`, `return` and `>>==` and  are under-represented.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Risk where

import Control.Monad.Random
import Control.Applicative
import Data.List
import Data.Functor.Identity

------------------------------------------------------------
-- Die values

newtype DieValue = DV { unDV :: Int } 
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Num)

first :: (a -> b) -> (a, c) -> (b, c)
first f (a, c) = (f a, c)

instance Random DieValue where
  random           = first DV . randomR (1,6)
  randomR (low,hi) = first DV . randomR (max 1 (unDV low), min 6 (unDV hi))

die :: Rand StdGen DieValue
die = getRandom

------------------------------------------------------------
-- MY CODE STARTS HERE
------------------------------------------------------------
-- Risk

-- Exercise 2

-- Given the definitions

type Army = Int

data Battlefield = Battlefield { attackers :: Army, defenders :: Army }

-- (which are also included in Risk.hs), write a function with the type

-- battle :: Battlefield -> Rand StdGen Battlefield

-- which simulates a single battle (as explained above) between two
-- opposing armies. That is, it should simulate randomly rolling the
-- appropriate number of dice, interpreting the results, and updating the
-- two armies to reflect casualties. You may assume that each layer will
-- attack or defend with the maximum number of units they are allowed.

roll n = sequence (replicate n die)

-- attacker can attack with x <= 3 armies, but must leave one in place
maxattackers :: Battlefield -> Int
maxattackers b = maximum [0, minimum[3, ((attackers b) - 1)]]

-- defender can defend with x <= 2 armies
maxdefenders :: Battlefield -> Int
maxdefenders b = maximum [0, minimum[2, (defenders b)]]

-- build [(a1,d1), (a2, d2), ...] pairs of dice rolls sorted and matched according to Risk! rules
fight attackers defenders = zip
                            <$> descending (roll attackers)
                            <*> descending (roll defenders) where descending =  fmap(reverse . sort) 

-- from list of rolls infer number of armies lost by each side
losses :: [(DieValue, DieValue)] -> (Int, Int)
losses ds =  (alosses ds,
              dlosses ds)
  where awins (x,y) = (x > y); -- Attacker wins when attacker's dice is strictly > 
        alosses = (length . filter (==False) . fmap awins); -- Attacker's losses is when attacker does not win
        dlosses = (length . filter (==True)  . fmap awins); -- Viceversa

battle :: Battlefield -> Rand StdGen Battlefield
battle b =
  let attacking = maxattackers b;
      defending = maxdefenders b in
      (updatefield . losses) <$> (fight attacking defending)
      where updatefield (alost,dlost) = (Battlefield (attackers b - alost) (defenders b - dlost))



-- Exercise 3

-- Of course, usually an attacker does not stop after just a single
-- battle, but attacks repeatedly in an attempt to destroy the entire
-- defending army (and thus take over its territory).

-- Now implement a function

-- invade :: Battlefield -> Rand StdGen Battlefield

-- which simulates an entire invasion attempt, that is, repeated calls to
-- battle until there are no defenders remaining, or fewer than two
-- attackers.

invade :: Battlefield -> Rand StdGen Battlefield
invade b = case b of
  Battlefield 1 _ -> return b
  Battlefield _ 0 -> return b
  otherwise -> battle b >>= invade

-- Exercise 4

-- Finally, implement a function

-- successProb :: Battlefield -> Rand StdGen Double

-- which runs invade 1000 times, and uses the results to compute a Double
-- between 0 and 1 representing the estimated probability that the
-- attacking army will completely destroy the defending army.

-- For example, if the defending army is destroyed in 300 of the 1000
-- simulations (but the attacking army is reduced to 1 unit in the other
-- 700), successProb should return 0.3.


-- take list [a] and return percentage of list elements satisfying given condition
percentageFilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Double
percentageFilter cond xs = (fromIntegral.length.(filter cond)) xs  /   (fromIntegral.length) xs

repeatInvasion :: Int -> Battlefield -> RandT StdGen Identity [Battlefield]
repeatInvasion n b = (sequence(replicate n (invade (b)))) 

successProb :: Battlefield -> Rand StdGen Double
successProb b = (percentageFilter attackerWins <$> (repeatInvasion 1000 b)) where attackerWins = ((==0).defenders)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks good to me: I have only minor suggestions:

**Use weaker functions when possible**

`maximum` works for a list of any length, while `max` for just two items, the same for `min`

```
maxattackers b = max 0 (min 3 ((attackers b) - 1))
```

The lack of square braces helps readability a bit.

**Small descriptively named functions**

In the above you are basically constraining `(attackers b) - 1` to be in `(0, 3)` range. I suggest writing a function for it, as you do that in `maxdefenders` too:

```
constrainToRange x (a, b) = max a (min b x)
```

And you get an improvement in readability and deduplicate:

```
maxattackers b = constrainToRange ((attackers b) - 1)) (0, 3)
maxdefenders b = constrainToRange (defenders b) (0, 2)
```

**Use filter directly**

When you say:

```
filter (==True) . fmap awins
```

It is equivalent to:

```
mfilter awins
```

That is simpler.

**Longer names and less repetition**

The `losses` function has non-descriptive names (`awins`?) and repetition:

```
        alosses = (length . filter (==False) . fmap awins); -- Attacker's losses is when attacker does not win
        dlosses = (length . filter (==True)  . fmap awins); -- Viceversa
```

Using `mfilter` as suggested above and taking advantage that the attacker `xor` the defender loses:

```
losses ds =  (attackerLosses, defensorLosses)
  where
    attackerWins (x,y) = (x > y)
    defensorLosses = length $ mfilter attackerWins ds
    attackerLosses = length ds - defensorLosses
```

Such names also make the comment redundant.

Comment: `constrainToRange` is also known as plain `clamp`.